# How to get the selected index from a dropdown menu in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have a dropdown menu in d3.js, and I would like to get the index from the selected option. It's a list of a bit more than 50 flight companies, and right now I have this :

```
  function choixCompagnie(){
    let compagnieChoisie = d3.select(this).property('value')
  }
```

This function activates whenever there is a change on the drop down, like so :

`d3.select("#selectCompagnie")
 .on("change",choixCompagnie)`

The `property('value')` means that for instance if I click the first line of my drop down menu, which is Aer Lingus, my `compagnieChoisie` variable will get the value `Aer Lingus` instead of `0`.

I need it because I then need to access some properties company by company, and my objects are in an array. So in my database I need to access the properties like this `data[index].randomProperty` and not like this `data["Company Name"].randomProperty`, since the company name is already a property.

I don't know if this makes sense, sorry if I'm using the wrong terms I'm fairly new to coding.

Thanks for the help !

edit : here is a working example http://blockbuilder.org/ArnaudStephanUNIL/a18332a561579eb929091faaff91fb6f, where the drop down gets the value but not the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better, easier way to get the index from a drop down menu :

```
<select id="selectOptions"></select>
```

Once you initialized your drop down menu, you simply have to do this :

```
var options = ["option1","option2"];

options.forEach(function(d,i){
    d3.select("#selectOptions")
      .append("option")
      .attr("value",i)
      .text(d);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access your data like this:

```
function choixCompagnie(){
    let compagnieChoisie = d3.select(this).property('value')
    console.log(data.find(d => d.compagnie === compagnieChoisie).accidents);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I found another method using d3.nest, but it seems like yours is more elegant :)

`d3.nest()
      .key(d=>d.compagnie)
      .map(data);`